# Linq Group by to get sum and count of data c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a dataset with four fields, (DriverNo, Airport, SumAmount, and count)
Airport can be many, sumAmount is the amount driver made from airport trip
I like to find out how many trips each driver had to airport and how much he earned.

So my retrived data should like something

[image]

My linq is like following but I doubt the result

```
var list = db.Booking1
  .Where(w => w.Gen_Location.LocationTypeId == 
                Enums.LOCATION_TYPES.AIRPORT)
  .Select(w => new
     {
       DriverNo = w.Fleet_Driver.DriverNo,
       Airport = w.Gen_Location.LocationName,
       Amount = w.CustomerPrice,
       driverId = w.DriverId
     })
  .GroupBy(w => w.Airport)
  .Select(w => new
     {
       DriverNo = w.First().DriverNo,
       Airport = w.First().Airport,
       SumAmount = w.Sum(a => a.Amount),
       driverId = w.First().driverId,
       count = w.Count()
     })
  .ToList();
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why are you doubting? What results do you get and what are you expecting to get? Also, that seems like an Entity Framework query, you should be able to get the raw SQL being executed and compare that to what you expect

Comment: Doubt is a good thing but it's not enought. You should produce a data sample and an expected output and verify the result using multiple test. Doubt is the 1rst step, then you should test and try.

Comment: @DragandDrop I checked database using queries so my linq is not getting right data

Comment: @Alex Does that resolve your question?

Answer (score 0):

> I like to find out how many trips each driver had to airport and how much he earned.

If that's the case you additionally need to group by the driver as well, right now your only grouping by the airport.  Then you can use your Key to obtain the data you need

```
var list = db.Booking1
  .Where(w => w.Gen_Location.LocationTypeId == 
            Enums.LOCATION_TYPES.AIRPORT)
   .Select(w => new
     {
       DriverNo = w.Fleet_Driver.DriverNo,
       Airport = w.Gen_Location.LocationName,
       Amount = w.CustomerPrice,
       driverId = w.DriverId
     })
  .GroupBy(w => new { w.Airport, w.DriverId})
  .Select(w => new
     {
       // You can put this in the key too but in this case
       // I'll grab it from the first element
       DriverNo = w.First().DriverNo,
       //It's more clear to get this from the key
       Airport = w.Key.Airport,
       SumAmount = w.Sum(a => a.Amount),
       //It's more clear to get this from the key
       driverId = w.Key.driverId,
       count = w.Count()
     })
  .ToList();
```

To be honest all of this should be in it's own classes. If you need to filter the data for a specific driver e.g 4.

```
list.Where(x => x.driverId == 4);
```

Comment: I like to know how many times each driver went to each airport. your query is not verifying my db

Comment: You have the data there, just filter by driver id. H/O ill make an edit